# Nontrivial upper bounds for the nullity of hyperplanes in paving matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\null{null}$Let $H$ be a hyperplane of the paving matroid $M$ with $r(M)=n$. How large can $\null(H)$ be?
We know that $\null(H)=|H|-r(H)=|H|-(n-1)$. So everything boils down to finding the size of the largest hyperplane in $M$.

Comment: Do you want the best possible upper bound for $|H|$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: (it does not seem to exist: take many generic points in a real hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and one vector outside)

Comment: Yes, an upper bound in terms of $n$. In general for an arbitrary matroid, it doesn't seem to be possible. But how about we restrict the discussion to paving matroids (which are pretty close to uniform matroids)? That is, every $n$- set is either a basis or very close to be a basis. @Fedro Petrov

Comment: I think, the matroid I am talking about is paving, since all circuits contain either $n$ or $n+1$ elements

Comment: I agree with Fedor's example. Alternatively, if you impose a given rank (say, $n$) and a given cardinality (say, $N$) you can find a paving matroid of rank $n$ and size $N$ having a hyperplane of cardinality $N-1$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks. Please write this as the answer so that I can award the 50 points bounty to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such bound. Take many vectors in a real hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general position, and one vector outside $H$. They form a paving matroid, since all circuits have size $n-1$ or $n$.